# Rails way to catch and handle exceptions

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm looking for the best way to catch and handle exceptions in a rails app from service classes.

I have a class which calls service x, service x returns an error if the user info is wrong. At the moment we handle the error and delete previously created objects in the DB.

```
class Main
...
error_response = ServiceX.new(hash).run

    if error_response
      StampRequest.delete(stamp_requests)
      raise StampError, error_response[:error]
    end
...
end
```

The problem is that service x calls several other services, including external an external AWS and currently if these services fail or cause an exception I'm not sure of the best way or 'rails way' to handle these errors and pass them back to the main class. Currently, if for example the call to the AWS service fails, the main class has no way of knowing this.

```
class ServiceX
...
return error_response unless subscribed_to_price_alert_users_available?(subscribed_to_price_alert_users)

    subscribed_to_price_alert_users.each do |user|
      PricingMailer.notify(user, user_hash(user)).deliver_later
      Sms::PricingSms.new(build_hash(user)).submit
      PricingService.new(user, reminder_hash(user)).submit unless reminders?
    end

    # return nil to indicate success
    nil
  end
...
end
```

If the external services fail I want to then delete the `StampRequests` from the DB as I do if there is a user error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing `nil` for success is not the best/right way.
Hope the below code snippet may help you.

```
class Main
  ...
  begin
    ServiceX.new(hash).run
  rescue StandardError, AWSError => exception
    ...
    StampRequest.delete(stamp_requests)
    raise StampError, exception.message
  end
end


class ServiceX
  ...
  raise StandardError.new(error_response) unless subscribed_to_price_alert_users_available?(subscribed_to_price_alert_users)

  # Assuming you have AWS/External service calls in this loop
  # Let it raise exception (AWSError), this has to be handled wisely by the caller of this function.
  # In this case caller: a fn in Main class, it has rescue block to handle this exception 
  subscribed_to_price_alert_users.each do |user|
    PricingMailer.notify(user, user_hash(user)).deliver_later
    Sms::PricingSms.new(build_hash(user)).submit
    PricingService.new(user, reminder_hash(user)).submit unless reminders?
  end
  ...
end
```